# What exactly interpret #!/bin/bash line?

Tags: linux, shell

Many scripts in different languages have a `#!/bin/bash` header with a path to interpreter, so they can be executed without explicit call to interpreter from command line.

But what exactly reads this line and run the interpreter, is it shell or kernel?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At least in Linux,the kernel has this functionality: fs/binfmt_script.c specifically.

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/06c2afb862f9da8dc5efa4b6076a0e48c3fbaaa5/fs/binfmt_script.c#L40

I imagine, however, that some shells may bypass this, and check the first line for an interpreter line rather than just calling exec and letting the kernel figure it out.

Comment: O.K. I think I miss understood question.

Comment: OK, after reading justin answerer I think my whole concept understanding was wrong

Comment: Now, I think It would be hard to bypass this.

Comment: It _used to be_ the shell. http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/shebang/ has lots of information and history.

Comment: Also, it is not a very good idea to link to Android source code when referring to Linux.

Comment: Actually, it wasn't Android specific source code, it was the Linux kernel source code as hosted on an Android site. I didn't want to provide a URL for a tarball of the kernel that would need to be untarred to get at the file. However, linking to that site turned out to not be a very good idea for a different, reason, it no longer seems to be up... At any rate, googling Linux binfmt_script.c will find other copies for anyone interested

Answer (score 5):

The kernel reads it.  It uses the #! to detect that the file is a script and not a binary, and  execs the command that follows.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)#As_magic_number explains how it works pretty well.