# Use of '#!' in *nix scripts

Tags: macos, unix, script, shell-script

In many Apple/Unix scripts I see stuff preceeded by '#" which as far as I know means it is a remark. However often you see shell calls as below (the line with `#!`).

```
## Setting a default route 
#!/bin/sh

/sbin/route add SUBNET $5
```

I am wondering whether this is also just a comment or that it actually does something. Thanks for your experts' advice :-)

Comment: nice question! +1

Comment: possible duplicate of [What exactly interpret #!/bin/bash line?](http://superuser.com/questions/117721/what-exactly-interpret-bin-bash-line)

Answer (score 16):

It's a way of defining of which shell should be invoked during execution of the script. It's called the [Shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29).

Example, a file having the following Shebang line:

```
#!/bin/sh
```

would invoke the Bourne (sh) shell. So for example, your piece of script:

```
## Setting a default route 
#!/bin/sh

/sbin/route add SUBNET $5
```

would make `/sbin/route add SUBNET $5` run in the Bourne shell interpreter. `/sbin/route add SUBNET $5` is just a comment and doesn't do anything. However, the shebang should be on the first line, therefore that comment at the top will disallow the shebang to do its work, making it a useless addition.

There's a number of interpreters that are widely used and some typical interpreters for shebang lines are:

- `#!/bin/sh` — Execute using sh, the Bourne shell (or a compatible shell)
- `#!/bin/csh` — Execute using csh, the C shell (or a compatible shell)
- `#!/usr/bin/perl` — Execute using Perl
- `#!/usr/bin/python` — Execute using Python
- `#!/usr/bin/php` — Execute using PHP's command line interpreter

As Olli mentioned in his comments, sometimes [`env`](http://swoolley.org/man.cgi/env) (short for environment) is used to make sure the correct path to the interpreter is chosen.

Comment: Actually for non-standard things (for example perl, python and php), it's better idea to use `env`: `#!/usr/bin/env perl`, for example. That'll automatically choose correct path for perl, even if it's not `/usr/bin`.

Comment: @Olli it's just some examples! ;) But you're right of course...

Comment: @BloodPhilia: if so, it may be good idea to edit those examples :)

Comment: The shebang has to be the first line so the initial commented line would prevent the second line from doing anything. Another style that's often used is `#!/usr/bin/env python` which will usually cause the script to be run by whatever `python` occurs first in the `PATH`. This is useful since sometimes executables are installed in different places so this works without having to modify the script. In a few rare cases, `env` is located somewhere else, so even this fails.

Comment: @Olli Happy now xD?

Comment: Well, and in a few rare cases there is no `/bin/sh` available. I would claim that `/usr/bin/env` is pretty much safe choice nowadays, especially compared to python/perl/php.

Comment: @Olli In a few rare cases, there's Windows installed... I can't cover every possiblity there ever can be... The OP just wants to know what the line means, not its best practices...

Comment: @Olli: Under the Filesystem Hierarchy Standard, "essential" programs which must be available in single-user mode must be placed in `/bin`, while `/usr` is for non-essential programs, so `/bin/sh` is a safer bet than `/usr/bin/env` - it's always possible that `/usr` may not be mounted, after all. I agree that `/usr/bin/env perl` is definitely better than `/usr/bin/perl`, though.

Comment: +1 for saying "the Bourne shell (or a compatible shell)". Some systems don't use Bourne shell, but still call it sh.

Comment: Thanks all foor the clear answers! Really helpful. Also thanks to BloodPhilia for the better formatting of my question.

Answer (score 4):

Somewhat more technical explanation:

When you run an executable on UNIX/Linux/Windows/SomeOS/AnyOS the system needs to know how to run it. In UNIX/Linux are special rules for the first few bytes of the files to tell the kernel how to run it. For scripts, the special characters are '#!'.  If The kernel sees this as the first two characters, it knows the file is a script and looks at the rest of the line for the executable that runs the script. So if the file /path/to/script.sh starts:

```
#!/bin/sh
```

The kernel would see '#!', know it is a script and find and run /bin/sh and pass the script file path /path/to/script.sh as a parameter. Since all script interpreters (bash, perl, csh, python, etc) use '#' as the comment character, they'll all just ignore this '[shebang](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Shebang_(Unix))' line as a comment.

You probably never saw this before because Windows handles this completely differently. On Windows, it doesn't use these 'magic' characters, but instead maps the file extension to the way to run it.